# SpringWebFlux - How to setup a default content type?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I want to put a default content-type when my api doesn't receive in the request, how can I do this in webFlux? I saw that it has a 'WebFluxConfigurer' class similar to 'WebMvcConfigurer' but I didn't find how to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `WebFilter` to transform the incoming request, adding your default `Content-Type` if the `Content-Type` header is missing on it

In this example, I am defaulting to `application/json`

```java
@Component
public class DefaultContentTypeWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        if (request.getHeaders().getContentType() == null) {
            exchange = exchange.mutate()
                    .request(request
                            .mutate()
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                            .build())
                    .build();
        }

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that one?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebFluxConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    public void configureContentTypeResolver(RequestedContentTypeResolverBuilder builder) {
        builder.fixedResolver(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```